# What am I doing wrong with my array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a program that receives data and then puts it into an array.  For reasons that I can't discern, after hours of pulling my hair out, the field "groupID" shows up as having been passed, but then (on the next line) as not being found.  Here is the code:

```
session_start(); // Start session first thing in script
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');


echo "what we sent: " ;
print_r($_GET);
$groupId = $_GET['groupId'];
$GroupName = $_GET['GroupName'];
$Price = $_GET['Price'];
$_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(
0 => array(
               "groupId" => $groupId, 
       "GroupName" => $GroupName, 
       "Price" => $Price
)  //array
); //array

echo "<br />";      
print_r ($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
```

The output of the program is as follows: 
what we sent:

`Array ( [newvalue] => 1 [theData] => groupId=1 [GroupName] => Urban Textures [StylePatternColor] => RBN TXTRS [KitDescription] => [StandardPutUp] => 270 [Price] => 1485 [Discount] => 1417 [DiscountNote] => 1 [Kit] => True [Quantity] => 1 )`

```
Notice: Undefined index: groupId in /home/acmeco5/public_html/AcmeComputingCart/cartUpdaterSimplified.php on line 10

Array ( [0] => Array ( [groupId] => [GroupName] => Urban Textures [Price] => 1485 ) )
```

Notice that the groupId shows up in the `$_GET` as having a value of 1, but on the next line it is undefined.

What am I doing wrong????

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `[theData] => groupId=1` is this a typo or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the `print_r` results wrong. Notice it says

```
[theData] => groupId=1
```

That means there is an element whose index is `theData`, whose value is `groupId=1`. NOT, an element whose index is `groupId`, which is what you are trying to use.

Comment: Ask a new question and include the relevant information about your AJAX call.

Comment: I guess the place I'm going wrong is in the program that creates the arrays.  Do you see what I need to do here? 
 var $form = $(this).closest('form'); // get the form element this button belongs to
    var theData = $form.serialize(); // generates the data string
 alert(theData);
// var id = $button.attr("id");
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "cartUpdaterSimplified.php?newvalue=" + newVal + "&theData=" + theData,
   success: function(data,status){
     $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
 // alert(
  
//     "RETURNED DATA:" + data+" items."
  
  
 // );
   }
 });

Comment: If you ask your question in a new question instead of as a comment, you will be able to format it so we can read it.

Comment: I know...but it won't let me ask another question for 90 minutes! Oh well...I will wait out the clock!  Thanks to you for your help.

Comment: In this expression `+ newVal + "&theData=" + theData`, try deleting `theData=`, but leave the `&`.

Comment: Sir, you are a gentleman and a scholar and I *truly* thank you.  That worked perfectly.  I will try to pass it forward.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
if(strpos($_GET[theData]),'='){
   $group = $_GET[theData];
   $groups  = explode('=',$group);
   $group_id  = $groups[1];
}else{
   $group_id  = $_GET[theData];
}
```

cheers..

Comment: Thanks.  Dwayne was right, it was a problem in the way I was passing via ajax.  Thanks for your help!